# Google Apps Script won't connect to MySQL database but will connect to free sql database server

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc

I'm trying to use Google Apps Script to connect to an SQL database provided by my hosting company. I know the credentials are correct because I'm able to access the database via PHPMyAdmin with no problem.

When I try to connect via Google Apps Script it's not working and I only get the exception error as follows:

```
Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username, and password.
```

I've tried/I'm Using:

- Appending the */"useSSL=false* at the end of the URL as recommended by other forums
- Jdbc.getConnection(url,user,pwd) for external databases
- Port 3306
- Creating a new database with new credentials to see if it was a corrupted database

Is there any way that it may be a setting inside PHPMyAdmin or any privileges I need from my hosting company?

Comment: Have your verified with your hosting company that your MySQL instance is publicly accessible (which has security implications), otherwise Google Apps cannot reach it. The PHPMyAdmin you use is likely inside the network of your hosting company, maybe even the same machine as your database, so the fact it can connect is not a real test.

Comment: Check with your hosting company's support staff.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I didn't even think of something like that. I was going to mention that the PHPMyAdmin dashboard did have one of the tabs missing from what some tutorials were explaining. I will give that a shot.

Comment: Have you managed to solve it? If not, can you update on your progress and share the code you are using without the personal information?

Comment: @Kessy, not yet. I haven't had a chance to speak to the hosting company as I am not the authorized user of the account. Once I am able to do so I will provide an update.